# Databinding in style to property on parent window

Tags: wpf, data-binding, styles, tooltip

Is it possible to declare a style that sets the fontsize of tooltips to the same size as the parent form? I have tried this...

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=FontSize}"/>
    </Style>
```

...but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=FontSize}"/>
    </Style>
```